# Getting error with ng new command in Angular CLI

Tags: angular

When I run `ng new myproject`, I get following error.

> "Unexpected end of JSON error while while parsing near ...": {"integrity": "sha51 '"

I am using MicroSoft Surface 6 Pro .

Comment: Can you try to uninstall and install the @angular/cli package again?

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this

```
npm cache clean --force
```

then run

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Comment: glad it works, can you accept it has answer